# Is there a way to get a variants stock quantity in commerce?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce3, variants

Like the question says. I know you can check if a variant is "in stock" with `v.hasStock`, but is there a way to pull the current stock quantity value?

In my particular situation I would like to do something like this:

`<input type="number" min="0" max="{{ variant.availableStock }} />`

So as to prevent users from inputing a quantity that the store doesn't have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
{{ variant.stock }}
```